# How to get both value and name of content in angular 5 binding?

Tags: angular5

Currently if I use ngModel I am able to save the name conent 
And if I use ngValue I am able to save the values of the content .

But I need both content and value of the selected drop-down ,
Please help me out of it .

```
<select [(ngModel)] = "bindingobject.studentId" name= " studentName">

<Option selected = true > Select <option>

<Option *ngFor = " let Stu of StudentEntity " value  = " {{Stu.studentId}} > {{Stu.studentName}}</option>
</Select>
```

So here I need to select both student name as well as id

Comment: Can you post sample code, so that we can see what exactly you are trying ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[ngValue]` to get the value as an object.

like this

```
<select [(ngModel)]="myDropDown" name="studentName">
<option *ngFor="let c of studentData" [ngValue]="c">> {{c.studentName}}</option>
</select>
```

this will treat the value as an object so you will get studentid and name both.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-p7yrzu?file=app/app.component.html)